# “Not enough storage is available to process this command.” for Mutex

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mutex

I post this question because I didn't find an answer to this question, so I think someone might need this solution.
I didn't provide my code because I can confirm the problem is occurring on mutex initialization. 
Here is the error message and call stack.

```
---> (Inner Exception #4) System.IO.IOException: Not enough storage is available to process this command. : 'ABCDEFGHIJK'
     at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew)
     at NormalizationService.Controllers.PhysicalChunkingController.Store(Chunk chunk, Stream bytes) in /usr/local/...
```

I have searched for solutions to this error message, and most of the solutions are like this page https://appuals.com/fix-not-enough-storage-available-process-command/. It can't solve my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found it is because I didn't release the mutex object. I thought it is lightweight, so I didn't need to release them.

However, my program will run parallelly and initialize about 200,000 mutex objects. And in my experiments, it rarely happened when I initialize about 160,000 mutex objects. So I guess only rare people will encounter this problem.

And I am not pretty sure why I get this error message instead of the regular mistake like the OutOfMemory Exception.